# Problem with Blogger OpenID

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I tried to join this site using my blogger.com OpenID - but it gave me an HTTP 414 error.  I have already joined several other stackexchange sites using my blogger ID, so it's either something from with photo.se or else there's some transient problem with the openID integration...

Answer (score 1):

If you received an HTTP 414, that is usually because the URL that the request was directed too was too long for one of the involved servers to handle. I am not sure that would really be a transient problem...it might have to do with the length of our site name...which is fairly long....the length of your user ID, or a combination of the lengths of various components involved in the interaction with blogger.com.

Hopefully one of the StackExchange Network admins will come along soon, as they have more power to help you out than we do.

Answer (score 1):

That is odd, particularly if it has worked with other sites in the network here -- is it still happening?

Comment: No, it's working now, and I've linked my account with my other SE accounts.  How do I merge the account I created here so I could ask that question now?  (i.e. the account that created this comment with the one that created the question)

Comment: ok, I merged the accounts